# Why is my CISD restart failing in PySCF?

Tags: python, high-performance-computing, pyscf, configuration-interaction, high-precision

## A case that works

In my answer to [Restarting an FCI calculation in PySCF](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9743/5), I provided a [folder full of input and output files](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/9743/cisd) that demonstrates saving (as a `numpy` array) a CI vector from a converged CISD calculation with a certain convergence tolerance, and using it as the starting point for a CISD calculation with a tighter convergence tolerance, can lead to convergence with the tighter convergence tolerance in fewer ***total*** Davidson iterations.

In particular, this is what it looks like when not using the above-described restrat procedure (I've removed the `e` vectors that you would see in [my original answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10192/5) in order to make the **`max|de|`** column more clear; and I've removed all lines that don't start with `davidson` so that it's easier to see how **`max|de|`** progresses):

```
davidson 0 3   |r|= 2.82             max|de|=  0.967     lindep= 0.321
davidson 1 6   |r|= 1.67             max|de|= -0.374     lindep= 0.795
davidson 2 9   |r|= 0.119            max|de|= -0.1       lindep= 0.935
davidson 3 12  |r|= 0.0309           max|de|= -0.00137   lindep= 0.798
davidson 4 15  |r|= 0.015            max|de|= -9.09e-05  lindep= 0.838
davidson 5 18  |r|= 0.00676          max|de|= -4.81e-05  lindep= 0.839
davidson 6 3   |r|= 0.00676          max|de|= -2e-15     lindep=    1
davidson 7 6   |r|= 0.00341          max|de|= -6.44e-06  lindep= 0.808
davidson 8 9   |r|= 0.00545          max|de|= -5.05e-06  lindep= 0.519
davidson 9 12  |r|= 0.0266           max|de|= -8.54e-05  lindep= 0.797
davidson 10 14 |r|= 0.0367           max|de|= -0.000247  lindep= 0.769
davidson 11 16 |r|= 0.0169           max|de|= -0.00023   lindep= 0.745
davidson 12 3  |r|= 0.0169           max|de|=  3.33e-15  lindep= 0.857
davidson 13 5  |r|= 0.0155           max|de|= -5.47e-05  lindep= 0.521
davidson 14 7  |r|= 0.0199           max|de|= -5e-05     lindep= 0.54
davidson 15 9  |r|= 0.0072           max|de|= -5.41e-05  lindep= 0.868
davidson 16 11 |r|= 0.00248          max|de|= -8.5e-06   lindep= 0.946
davidson 17 12 |r|= 0.00141          max|de|= -1.45e-06  lindep= 0.805
davidson 18 13 |r|= 0.00467          max|de|= -4.16e-06  lindep= 0.954
davidson 19 14 |r|= 0.0131           max|de|= -2.79e-05  lindep= 0.916
davidson 20 15 |r|= 0.0129           max|de|= -0.000103  lindep= 0.938
davidson 21 16 |r|= 0.00397          max|de|= -2.14e-05  lindep= 0.879
davidson 22 3  |r|= 0.00397          max|de|=  5.03e-12  lindep= 0.995
davidson 23 4  |r|= 0.00169          max|de|= -1.86e-06  lindep= 0.818
davidson 24 6  |r|= 0.000331         max|de|= -2.66e-07  lindep= 0.92
davidson 25 8  |r|= 9.6e-05          max|de|= -1.48e-08  lindep= 0.892
davidson 26 9  |r|= 4.79e-05         max|de|= -1.45e-09  lindep= 0.775
davidson 27 10 |r|= 9.55e-05         max|de|= -7.29e-10  lindep= 0.446
davidson 28 11 |r|= 0.00012          max|de|= -1.91e-09  lindep= 0.607
davidson 29 13 |r|= 0.000161         max|de|= -8.3e-09   lindep=  0.9
davidson 30 15 |r|= 0.000134         max|de|= -7.21e-09  lindep= 0.894
davidson 31 17 |r|= 9.8e-05          max|de|= -4.61e-09  lindep= 0.838
davidson 32 3  |r|= 9.79e-05         max|de|=  9.03e-09  lindep= 0.999
davidson 33 4  |r|= 9.76e-05         max|de|= -2.65e-09  lindep= 0.835
davidson 34 5  |r|= 6.05e-05         max|de|= -2.83e-09  lindep= 0.913
davidson 35 6  |r|= 3.02e-05         max|de|= -1e-09     lindep= 0.738
converged 36 7 |r|= 2.1e-05          max|de|= -1.36e-10
RCISD converged
```

This is what it looks like when I do the above with `conv_tol=1e-5` instead of `conv_tol=1e-9` (notice that until the `davidson 16` line, the **`max|de|`** values are almost identical to the above case):

```
davidson 0 3   |r|= 2.82             max|de|=  0.967     lindep= 0.321
davidson 1 6   |r|= 1.67             max|de|= -0.374     lindep= 0.795
davidson 2 9   |r|= 0.119            max|de|= -0.1       lindep= 0.935
davidson 3 12  |r|= 0.0309           max|de|= -0.00137   lindep= 0.798
davidson 4 15  |r|= 0.015            max|de|= -9.09e-05  lindep= 0.838
davidson 5 18  |r|= 0.00676          max|de|= -4.81e-05  lindep= 0.839
davidson 6 3   |r|= 0.00676          max|de|= -2e-15     lindep=    1
davidson 7 5   |r|= 0.00344          max|de|= -6.42e-06  lindep= 0.808
davidson 8 7   |r|= 0.00543          max|de|= -5.02e-06  lindep= 0.738
davidson 9 9   |r|= 0.0262           max|de|= -8.09e-05  lindep= 0.577
davidson 10 11 |r|= 0.0347           max|de|= -0.000254  lindep= 0.775
davidson 11 13 |r|= 0.0214           max|de|= -0.000281  lindep= 0.888
davidson 12 15 |r|= 0.0152           max|de|= -0.000131  lindep= 0.815
davidson 13 16 |r|= 0.0217           max|de|= -0.000125  lindep= 0.84
davidson 14 3  |r|= 0.0217           max|de|= 6e-15      lindep= 0.988
davidson 15 4  |r|= 0.00936          max|de|= -5.92e-05  lindep= 0.804
davidson 16 5  |r|= 0.00678          max|de|= -2.44e-05  lindep= 0.867
davidson 17 6  |r|= 0.00551          max|de|= -1.57e-05  lindep= 0.691
davidson 18 7  |r|= 0.00339          max|de|= -3.89e-06  lindep= 0.443
converged 19 8 |r|= 0.00132          max|de|= -8.5e-07
RCISD converged
```

This is what it looks like when restarting from the result directly above, and switching `conv_tol` back to `1e-9`:

```
davidson 0  3  |r|= 0.00132          max|de|=  0.805     lindep= 0.816
davidson 1  6  |r|= 0.000962         max|de|= -2.48e-07  lindep= 0.506
davidson 2  9  |r|= 0.000859         max|de|= -1.32e-07  lindep= 0.63
davidson 3  11 |r|= 0.00165          max|de|= -3.75e-07  lindep= 0.796
davidson 4  13 |r|= 0.00418          max|de|= -3.88e-06  lindep= 0.939
davidson 5  14 |r|= 0.00519          max|de|= -1.15e-05  lindep= 0.892
davidson 6  15 |r|= 0.00117          max|de|= -4.14e-06  lindep= 0.914
davidson 7  16 |r|= 0.00041          max|de|= -1.66e-07  lindep= 0.775
davidson 8  3  |r|= 0.00041          max|de|=  9.11e-11  lindep= 0.999
davidson 9  4  |r|= 0.000371         max|de|= -3.54e-08  lindep= 0.692
davidson 10 5  |r|= 0.000219         max|de|= -4.39e-08  lindep= 0.929
davidson 11 6  |r|= 7.38e-05         max|de|= -7.99e-09  lindep= 0.781
converged 12 7 |r|= 3.04e-05         max|de|= -7.2e-10
RCISD converged
```

## A case that does not work

The following input file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import numpy as np
import pyscf
from pyscf.gto.basis import parse_gaussian
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, fci, ci

mol = pyscf.M(
    atom = 'H 0 0 0; H 0 0 1.4011',
    unit = 'bohr',
    basis = {
            'H' : parse_gaussian.load('/home/nike/AI_ENERGIES/H/av6z.gbs', 'H')
    },
    charge = 0,
    spin = 0,
    verbose = 9,
    symmetry = True,
    symmetry_subgroup = 'Dooh',
)

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################
mf = mol.RHF().set(conv_tol=1e-10,max_cycle=999,direct_scf_tol=1e-14,chkfile = 'a6z.chk')
#mf.init_guess='atom'
#mf.init_guess='a10z.chk'
mf.kernel()

#####################
## post-Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mci = ci.CISD(mf).set(conv_tol=1e-5,max_cycle=999,nroots=27)
#mci.direct = True
e, civec = mci.kernel()
#e, civec = mci.kernel(ci0=np.load('civec.npy'))
np.save('civec.npy', civec)

#####################
## END OF INPUT
#####################
```

gives the following output (again with the `e` vectors removed and alignment adjustments so that the output is easier to raed):

```
davidson 0  27  |r|= 0.306    max|de|=  1.28      lindep= 0.317
davidson 1  54  |r|= 0.228    max|de|= -0.0578    lindep= 0.237
davidson 2  81  |r|= 0.361    max|de|= -0.041     lindep= 0.656
davidson 3  27  |r|= 0.361    max|de|= -1.16e-09  lindep= 0.723
davidson 4  54  |r|= 0.353    max|de|= -0.0399    lindep= 0.333
davidson 5  81  |r|= 0.332    max|de|= -0.0695    lindep= 0.355
davidson 6  27  |r|= 0.332    max|de|= -2.87e-08  lindep= 0.474
davidson 7  36  |r|= 0.251    max|de|= -0.0333    lindep= 0.362
davidson 8  43  |r|= 0.133    max|de|= -0.0115    lindep= 0.707
davidson 9  49  |r|= 0.0693   max|de|= -0.00816   lindep= 0.855
davidson 10 51  |r|= 0.0425   max|de|= -0.00192   lindep= 0.734
davidson 11 53  |r|= 0.0214   max|de|= -0.000329  lindep= 0.813
davidson 12 55  |r|= 0.0119   max|de|= -0.000104  lindep= 0.792
davidson 13 57  |r|= 0.00687  max|de|= -3.89e-05  lindep= 0.69
davidson 14 58  |r|= 0.00315  max|de|= -1.09e-05  lindep= 0.791
converged 15 59  |r|= 0.00244 max|de|= -2.53e-06
RCISD converged
```

When I "restart" this calculation with a smaller `conv_tol` value and using the `civec.npy` file from the previous calculation:

```
mci = ci.CISD(mf).set(conv_tol=1e-6,max_cycle=999,nroots=28)
e, civec = mci.kernel(ci0=np.load('civec.npy'))
```

I get ***results that are significantly worse***:

```
davidson 0   27  |r|= 0.00244 max|de|=  1.02    lindep= 0.809
davidson 1   54  |r|= 3.26    max|de|= -0.0404  lindep= 0.694
davidson 2   66  |r|= 0.523   max|de|= -0.953   lindep= 0.278
davidson 3   28  |r|= 0.48    max|de|= -0.0422  lindep= 0.198
davidson 4   34  |r|= 0.178   max|de|= -0.032   lindep= 0.111
davidson 5   40  |r|= 1.07    max|de|=  0.11    lindep= 0.0356
davidson 6   46  |r|= 0.224   max|de|= -0.148   lindep= 0.00736
davidson 7   52  |r|= 1.55    max|de|=  0.614   lindep= 0.00343
davidson 8   59  |r|= 0.383   max|de|= -0.481   lindep= 0.000585
davidson 9   66  |r|= 1.43    max|de|=  0.481   lindep= 0.000675
davidson 10  28  |r|= 1.26    max|de|=  0.0416  lindep= 0.225
davidson 11  38  |r|= 0.183   max|de|= -0.0698  lindep= 0.0414
davidson 12  47  |r|=  1.3    max|de|=  0.76    lindep= 0.0137
davidson 13  57  |r|= 0.506   max|de|= -0.775   lindep= 0.00197
davidson 14  67  |r|= 0.335   max|de|= -0.0292  lindep= 0.00103
davidson 15  28  |r|= 0.213   max|de|=  0.055   lindep= 0.138
davidson 16  38  |r|= 0.72    max|de|= -0.0243  lindep= 0.0141
davidson 17  49  |r|= 0.286   max|de|= -0.184   lindep= 0.00154
davidson 18  60  |r|= 0.274   max|de|= -0.00263 lindep= 0.00017
davidson 19  71  |r|= 0.815   max|de|=  0.308   lindep= 7.68e-05
davidson 20  28  |r|= 0.815   max|de|=  0.0582  lindep= 0.128
davidson 21  41  |r|= 0.813   max|de|= -0.206   lindep= 0.0214
davidson 22  55  |r|= 1.17    max|de|=  0.165   lindep= 0.00475
davidson 23  70  |r|= 1.23    max|de|= -0.415   lindep= 0.00107
davidson 24  28  |r|=  1.3    max|de|=  0.0979  lindep= 0.123
davidson 25  44  |r|= 1.09    max|de|= -0.403   lindep= 0.00725
davidson 26  60  |r|= 1.24    max|de|=  0.401   lindep= 0.000936
davidson 27  77  |r|= 1.22    max|de|= -0.669   lindep= 0.00155
davidson 28  28  |r|= 1.22    max|de|=  0.291   lindep= 0.143
davidson 29  46  |r|= 1.51    max|de|= -0.406   lindep= 0.00606
davidson 30  66  |r|= 0.774   max|de|= -0.409   lindep= 0.0109
davidson 31  28  |r|= 0.628   max|de|=  0.122   lindep= 0.118
davidson 32  49  |r|= 0.73    max|de|= -0.107   lindep= 0.0052
davidson 33  71  |r|= 0.944   max|de|=  0.227   lindep= 0.000678
davidson 34  28  |r|= 0.955   max|de|=  0.181   lindep= 0.126
davidson 35  50  |r|= 0.907   max|de|= -0.216   lindep= 0.00234
davidson 36  68  |r|= 0.534   max|de|= -0.145   lindep= 0.000781
davidson 37  28  |r|= 0.391   max|de|=  0.0416  lindep= 0.0934
davidson 38  51  |r|= 0.896   max|de|=  0.0729  lindep= 0.00274
davidson 39  72  |r|= 1.05    max|de|=  0.261   lindep= 0.000494
davidson 40  28  |r|= 1.04    max|de|= -0.145   lindep= 0.132
davidson 41  54  |r|= 0.872   max|de|= -0.328   lindep= 0.00481
davidson 42  72  |r|=  1.2    max|de|=  0.265   lindep= 0.000577
davidson 43  28  |r|=  1.2    max|de|=  0.113   lindep= 0.123
davidson 44  56  |r|= 0.926   max|de|= -0.246   lindep= 0.00102
davidson 45  74  |r|= 0.515   max|de|= -0.244   lindep= 0.000294
davidson 46  28  |r|= 0.323   max|de|=  0.0482  lindep= 0.156
davidson 47  54  |r|= 0.15    max|de|= -0.0714  lindep= 0.0188
davidson 48  71  |r|= 0.39    max|de|=  0.00182 lindep= 0.00268
davidson 49  28  |r|= 0.398   max|de|=  0.0692  lindep= 0.123
davidson 50  54  |r|= 0.682   max|de|= -0.0383  lindep= 0.00184
davidson 51  66  |r|= 0.535   max|de|= -0.121   lindep= 0.000584
davidson 52  28  |r|= 0.522   max|de|=  0.0788  lindep= 0.217
davidson 53  52  |r|= 0.477   max|de|= -0.0799  lindep= 0.0475
davidson 54  65  |r|= 0.282   max|de|= -0.0426  lindep= 0.00548
davidson 55  75  |r|= 0.313   max|de|= -0.0138  lindep= 0.00125
davidson 56  28  |r|= 0.286   max|de|=  0.078   lindep= 0.183
davidson 57  50  |r|= 0.773   max|de|= -0.0439  lindep= 0.00725
davidson 58  65  |r|= 0.511   max|de|= -0.13    lindep= 0.00639
davidson 59  80  |r|= 0.561   max|de|= -0.0389  lindep= 0.00332
davidson 60  28  |r|= 0.436   max|de|=  0.139   lindep= 0.226
davidson 61  53  |r|=  0.7    max|de|= -0.0786  lindep= 0.295
davidson 62  70  |r|= 0.467   max|de|= -0.112   lindep= 0.0113
davidson 63  28  |r|= 0.411   max|de|=  0.131   lindep= 0.231
davidson 64  53  |r|= 0.593   max|de|= -0.0579  lindep= 0.06
davidson 65  71  |r|= 0.579   max|de|= -0.0811  lindep= 0.0167
davidson 66  28  |r|= 0.41    max|de|=  0.156   lindep= 0.221
davidson 67  56  |r|= 0.561   max|de|= -0.0616  lindep= 0.0926
davidson 68  76  |r|= 0.521   max|de|= -0.0812  lindep= 0.0288
```

It continued like that until the calculation job timed out after `davidson 608`:

```
davidson 601 56  |r|= 0.419   max|de|= -0.0211  lindep= 0.0172
davidson 602 83  |r|= 0.37    max|de|= -0.13    lindep= 0.0116
davidson 603 28  |r|= 0.306   max|de|=  0.0743  lindep= 0.224
davidson 604 56  |r|= 0.402   max|de|= -0.0317  lindep= 0.0255
davidson 605 79  |r|= 0.35    max|de|= -0.0622  lindep= 0.0292
davidson 606 28  |r|= 0.271   max|de|=  0.0528  lindep= 0.222
davidson 607 56  |r|= 0.427   max|de|= -0.0196  lindep= 0.0186
davidson 608 81  |r|= 0.405   max|de|= -0.0856  lindep= 0.0531
```

It's good to see that the `|r|` values match:

```
converged 15 59  |r|= 0.00244 max|de|= -2.53e-06
davidson 0   27  |r|= 0.00244 max|de|=  1.02    lindep= 0.809
```

However, the `max|de|` value for the `davidson 0` in the "restarted" calculation is closer to what we had at the beginning of the ***first*** calculation:

```
davidson 0  27  |r|= 0.306    max|de|=  1.28      lindep= 0.317
```

In the "restarted" calculation, the `|r|` value gets bad at `davidson 1` and the `max|de|` and `lindep` values go bad very soon after.

## Question

Why is the restart not working in the second case, like it did for the first case?

Answer (score 1):

To prioritize other people's questions in search results for unanswered questions, I'm taking this out of the unanswered queue.

If have also [promised to put a bounty on this question if someone does answer it and warns me in advance](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/5).

If you want to answer this question, let me know and I'll remove this Community Wiki answer!